# How do I access the Monica HQ API with Python?

Tags: python, rest, request

I'm having some trouble accessing the API for Monicahq.com. I'm a very junior developer and I'm currently learning how to use GET requests to pull data from a web app using Python.

I've looked up some online guides and it's clear that I need to use the 'requests' package, as well as supply my access token (which I've obtained). I'm just not sure what code to write. This is what I have so far:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://app.monicahq.com/settings/api', headers={'authorization': 'Token XXXXXX'})

print(response.text)
```

All I'm getting is the html webpage for Monica. I think the problem might be that I'm not using the right link, but I'm not sure exactly which link I should be using to connect to the server? And then how would I get the JSON for the reminders that I have on my account?  The API Documentation is here if that helps anyone. https://www.monicahq.com/api/reminders

Sorry if this is a super newbie question, but that's what I am right now, and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: what are you expecting to get back? usually an api has some other parameters that you need to pass

Comment: also try `https://app.monicahq.com/settings/api/reminders/` as the url instead

Comment: I'm trying to obtain a JSON of the reminders that I have that are coming up! I want to be able to access these reminders, so that maybe they can be sent to me in an email, via IFTTT or something.

Comment: Usually, the header is `Authorization`, not `authorization`. Notice that it should be uppercase, not lowercase. Have you tried changing the lowercase header to uppercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API seems really crummy, but i think this works.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

url=r'https://monicahq.com/api/reminders'
headers={
'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXX'
}
#get response
r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
#make soup
soup=bs(r.text,'html.parser')
#extract json out of mess of html
j=json.loads(soup.find('code',{'class':'json'}).text)
#now j is the json object
print(j)
>{'data': [{'id': 2,
   'object': 'reminder',
   'title': 'Wish happy birthday to Danny',.....
```

The documentation is outdated or there is some other issue, i could never get the api to return just json like it says it will.

i also reccomend you remove your api key from the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do I have to use 'Bearer'? Also it was a fake API key but I'll remove it anyways.

Comment: i believe you do, or so the docs say. If it's fake you can leave it, may be helpful

Comment: Can you give me a link to where the doc says so?

Comment: Also I seem to be getting reminders for people who aren't on my contact list, even though I replaced XXXXX with my own API Key

Comment: I seem to be getting a static page - I have no idea who this 'Danny' guy is, but he shows up in my reminders as well as yours...

Comment: Yea i think you're right. without a real key i can't be sure, but try using the header i have above but with your real key, and `https://app.monicahq.com/api/reminders` as the url

Answer (score 0):

You can see on the api doc reference, the keyword for the header authentication is "Bearer": https://www.monicahq.com/api#authentication
As Monica uses Laravel, it's also descibed on this page: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#passing-the-access-token